# Data step merge PROC SQL equivalent flagging which table record was found in

Tags: sas

I merge two data sets as follows:

```
data ds3;
  merge ds1(in=in1) ds2(in=in2);
  by mrgvar;
  if in1;
  if in2 then flag=1;
run;
```

If I were to do this with a `PROC SQL` step instead, how can I set the `flag` variable as above?

```
proc sql;
  create table ds3 as
  select a.*
        ,b.*
        ,???
  from ds1 as a
       left join
       ds2 as b
       on a.mrgvar=b.mrgvar;
quit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way is to use the table alias with the join variable.

```
proc sql;
  create table ds3 as
  select a.*
        ,b.*
        ,case when b.mrgvar is null then 0 else 1 end as flag
  from ds1 as a
       left join
       ds2 as b
       on a.mrgvar=b.mrgvar;
quit;
```

Something to that effect - if b.mrgvar is null/missing then it's only coming from table a.  (Yes, you can separately reference the two even though they're basically the same and get combined in the result table.)